# Application sporadically crashes, having difficulty debugging

Tags: ios

I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash with code=1, and I am having difficulty interpreting the backtrace. When it crashes, the last line before it gets to assembly is showing everything with the proper memory, and nothing is nil.

From the backtrace it seems that there are a lot of things going on leading up to the crash. I would really appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**
Here is the new backtrace:

```
* thread #4: tid = 0x7126c, 0x00000001922bd2c0 libsystem_platform.dylib`OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32Barrier + 24, queue = 'com.example.tangible'
    frame #0: 0x00000001922bd2c0 libsystem_platform.dylib`OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32Barrier + 24
    frame #1: 0x00000001922c1ef0 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_rwlock_unlock + 168
    frame #2: 0x0000000191b5a8bc libobjc.A.dylib`class_copyProtocolList + 248
    frame #3: 0x000000018529fdf0 CoreFoundation`__methodDescriptionForSelector + 60
    frame #4: 0x00000001851c71f0 CoreFoundation`-[NSObject(NSObject) methodSignatureForSelector:] + 44
    frame #5: 0x0000000188111084 SpriteKit`-[SKThreadSafeMapTable methodSignatureForSelector:] + 116
    frame #6: 0x000000018529d81c CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 204
    frame #7: 0x00000001851bd78c CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    frame #8: 0x000000018811c330 SpriteKit`+[SKTexture lookupTextureCacheForName:] + 36
    frame #9: 0x000000018811dbec SpriteKit`-[SKTexture initTextureCacheWithImageData] + 56
    frame #10: 0x000000018811ecb0 SpriteKit`-[SKTexture initWithImageNamed:] + 232
    frame #11: 0x000000018811f6e8 SpriteKit`+[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:] + 68
    frame #12: 0x000000018813e05c SpriteKit`-[SKSpriteNode initWithImageNamed:] + 44
  * frame #13: 0x00000001000c7d04 Tangible`-[ControlScene addBlockToScreen:](self=0x0000000125617be0, _cmd=0x000000010052a4da, block=0x00000001786f7580) + 436 at ControlScene.mm:243
    frame #14: 0x00000001000c5aa8 Tangible`-[ControlScene updateDisplay](self=0x0000000125617be0, _cmd=0x0000000189cd2290) + 876 at ControlScene.mm:114
    frame #15: 0x00000001000c9950 Tangible`-[ControlScene updateBlocks:](self=0x0000000125617be0, _cmd=0x0000000100529bc8, b=0x0000000178851e50) + 348 at ControlScene.mm:357
    frame #16: 0x00000001000bbdb4 Tangible`-[StageViewController frameReady:](self=0x0000000125509670, _cmd=0x0000000100529bd6, frame=<unavailable>) + 640 at StageViewController.mm:94
    frame #17: 0x00000001000bfb5c Tangible`-[VideoSource captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:](self=0x000000017026ccc0, _cmd=0x0000000183fe21c9, captureOutput=0x000000017022dea0, sampleBuffer=0x0000000129116b10, connection=0x000000017041d410) + 340 at VideoSource.mm:131
    frame #18: 0x0000000183f683c4 AVFoundation`__74-[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput _AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_VideoDataBecameReady]_block_invoke + 412
    frame #19: 0x000000019212c014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    frame #20: 0x000000019212bfd4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #21: 0x00000001921324a8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain + 640
    frame #22: 0x000000019212e4c0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 68
    frame #23: 0x00000001921330f4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 104
    frame #24: 0x00000001921334fc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 76
    frame #25: 0x00000001922c16bc libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 356
```

Here is the code around line 234:

```
-(void)addBlockToScreen:(Block *) block {
    //NSLog(@"start");
    Block *copy = [[Block alloc] initWithCode:block.code x:block.x y:block.y];
    //NSLog(@"block copied");
    NSString *copyStr = [NSString stringWithString:copy.imageName];
    //NSLog(@"str created");
    if ([copyStr length]>0) {
        //NSLog(@"1: %@", copyStr);
        SKSpriteNode * shape = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:copyStr];
        shape.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, .5);
        shape.position = [self returnPointForX:copy.x+copy.trueX*1.68 Y:copy.y+copy.trueY*1.68];
        [self addChild:shape];
        shape.name = @"block";
    }
    //NSLog(@"done");
}
```

I've played around a lot trying to fix this crash. No way copyStr should be nil right? It is crashing at the "SKSpriteNode * shape = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:copyStr];" line.

**Second edit:**
The code crashed in a different time, this time in the opencv framework. I haven't changed the code at all. Maybe this is related?..

```
* thread #4: tid = 0x72a0f, 0x0000000192229bd4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`_kernelrpc_mach_vm_deallocate_trap + 8, queue = 'com.example.tangible'
    frame #0: 0x0000000192229bd4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`_kernelrpc_mach_vm_deallocate_trap + 8
    frame #1: 0x0000000192229e1c libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_vm_deallocate + 32
    frame #2: 0x0000000192272958 libsystem_malloc.dylib`deallocate_pages + 68
    frame #3: 0x00000001922728cc libsystem_malloc.dylib`free_large + 368
    frame #4: 0x0000000100080404 Tangible`cv::Mat::release(this=0x0000000100dfbb40) + 128 at mat.hpp:367
    frame #5: 0x000000010008032c Tangible`~Mat(this=0x0000000100dfbb40) + 32 at mat.hpp:276
    frame #6: 0x0000000100080138 Tangible`~Mat(this=0x0000000100dfbb40) + 28 at mat.hpp:275
    frame #7: 0x0000000100087f70 Tangible`-[StageViewController frameReady:](self=0x000000014fe0f330, _cmd=0x00000001004f5bd6, frame=<unavailable>) + 1108 at StageViewController.mm:140
  * frame #8: 0x000000010008bb44 Tangible`-[VideoSource captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:](self=0x000000017826c1c0, _cmd=0x0000000183fe21c9, captureOutput=0x000000017003bb20, sampleBuffer=0x0000000153906560, connection=0x0000000170619fc0) + 340 at VideoSource.mm:131
    frame #9: 0x0000000183f683c4 AVFoundation`__74-[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput _AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_VideoDataBecameReady]_block_invoke + 412
    frame #10: 0x000000019212c014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    frame #11: 0x000000019212bfd4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #12: 0x00000001921324a8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain + 640
    frame #13: 0x000000019212e4c0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 68
    frame #14: 0x00000001921330f4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 104
    frame #15: 0x00000001921334fc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 76
    frame #16: 0x00000001922c16bc libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 356

inline void Mat::release()
{
    if( refcount && CV_XADD(refcount, -1) == 1 )
        deallocate();
    data = datastart = dataend = datalimit = 0;
    size.p[0] = 0;
    refcount = 0;
}
```

Comment: Add your code of ControlScene.mm line 111 and around. Also mark which line 111 in your added code is. It should contain `NSLog` according to the stack trace.

Comment: Just as a tip. There are reports of people having problems when doing UI related tasks (adding/removing nodes) inside blocks in iOS8. May not be the case, but no harm in checking.

Comment: I am currently testing in iOS7, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the code.